# Remove elements from Guava Cache

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, guava

I am using `import com.google.common.cache.Cache`

I have initiated the cache this way:

```
private Cache<String,String> mycache =CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .concurrencyLevel(4).expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

I am willing to remove entries manually in some scenarios before waiting for the expiration.

The only way I found to do this was this:

```
mycache.asMap().remove("somekey");
```

I am asking if that is the proper way of doing this? Am I going to have any problems with that?

Comment: This wont remove the key if the map is a copy of the real data (to protect it) or of the map is remote and/or distributed. So use the invalidate method which is part of the API.

Comment: @tgkprog Not according to the [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap()). It just lists risks with iterators created from the map. But indeed, there's no reason not to use the API method.

Comment: Your right if you need to remove an item during iteration use the remove method of the map. Its must be overloaded to let the main cache know and to not fail itself.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The proper way of doing it would be to use the `invalidate` method:

```
mycache.invalidate("somekey");
```

As specified in the [API documentation](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidate(java.lang.Object)(java.lang.Object)):

> `void invalidate(Object key)`
>   Discards any cached value for key `key`.

Comment: In my case of doing so, my IDE is yielding back this error: `'invalidate(java.lang.Object)' is declared in unstable interface 'com.google.common.cache.Cache' marked with @Beta`

Comment: @Zap The `Cache` interface transitioned out of beta in Guava 19, which was released in 2015. I'd say  it's time to update.

Answer (score 8):

You should be using `invalidate(key)` method to remove individual elements.For bulk removal you can use `invalidateAll(keys)` method.

In your case you can use

```
mycache.invalidate("somekey");
```

Hope this solves your problem.